# Filling mat-layout-grid-cell with component in matblazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, matblazor

I'm creating MatBlazor application using Layout Grid. I have a button component, and I want it to fill it's cell completely. How do I extend component to fill its cell?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you are trying to get a component to fill its parent. You should be able to achieve this by adding CSS to your component.
Try:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Also remove any padding/margin.